# Behavior of streams created via cudaStreamCreate versus cudaStreamCreateWithFlags?

Tags: cuda

I notice that `cudaStreamCreate` is a `__host__`-only function, but `cudaStreamCreateWithFlags` is a `__host__ __device__` function.

Is there an important difference between the two that makes `cudaStreamCreate` unavailable in `__device__` functions?

I see this [documentation for the `cudaStreamCreateWithFlags` flags parameter](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#ixzz47ej8skSe):

> Creates a new asynchronous stream. The flags argument determines the
>   behaviors of the stream. Valid values for flags are
>
> - `cudaStreamDefault`: Default stream creation flag.
> - `cudaStreamNonBlocking`: Specifies that work running in the created
>     stream may run concurrently with work in stream 0 (the NULL stream),
>     and that the created stream should perform no implicit synchronization
>     with stream 0.

What precisely does "Default stream creation flag" mean? How will the created stream behave?

Comment: cudaStreamCreate is an exact synonym of cudaStreamCreateWithFlags using cudaStreamDefault argument.

Comment: Thanks @FlorentDUGUET! I'll answer with your response in order to move this off the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of

```
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamDefault);
```

is identical to

```
cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
```

except that `cudaStreamCreate` is a `__host__` function and `cudaStreamCreateWithFlags` is a `__host__ __device__` function.